# Web Safe fonts - What exactly does that mean?

Tags: html, fonts

I know which fonts are web safe font but I'm not sure about the definition: Is a web safe font one that your browser support or a font that is installed on your Operating System? So, if a font cannot be displayed in your browser, is it because your browser cannot render the font or is it because the font is not installed on your operating system?

Thank You

Comment: If the font you've specified is not on the user's system then browser default font will be loaded, and to be safe you can always rely on `arial`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web-safe_fonts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A web safe font is one that is installed on the majority of systems. (A font doesn't become safe just because someone installs it, it is safe if it is reasonable to assume that it will be available).

Support in browsers for the fonts is implicit.

Answer (score 7):

“Web safe font” is a vague and poorly named idea, and not very modern. It has been used to refer to fonts that are (assumed to be) installed on “all” or “most” computers; it’s at most “most” in reality, but the word “safe” in the name of the concept suggests “all”.

The idea implies that a web author specifies a font in CSS (or, in the old days, `<font>` tag in HTML). This means that browsers will use the font if properly installed in the system, e.g. placed in the Fonts folder on Windows.

No font is really “safe”, i.e. installed on all systems, but some fonts come close. There is no hard, reliable statistics on this, but reasonably good estimates.

The more modern approach is to use “font stacks”, or more prosaically lists of fonts. For example, the simple “stack” of `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif` is probably as web-safe as you ever need to get, but you are only “safe” in getting one of the three rather similar fonts.

So called web fonts, or downloadable fonts, used via `@font face` in CSS, are “safe” in the sense that the font will be used no matter what fonts are installed on each computer. They are not safe in other ways, though; the use of such fonts might be disabled in a browser (or unsupported in old browsers), and the download of a font might fail for a variety of reasons, like Internet fetches in general. Moreover, browser have bugs in their implementations, possibly resulting in distorted display of a font.

Answer (score 2):

A web safe font is one that is installed on your computer. This includes fonts installed from Photoshop or any other program.

As you can imagine, not many people have Photoshop! For this reason many fonts from Photoshop are considered **not** web-safe fonts.

A common list of web safe fonts can be found [here](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html).

If you would like to use different fonts i strongly suggest [font face](http://www.font-face.com/).

Comment: Isn't a font that requires Photoshop to be installed the opposite of web-safe?

Comment: I was answering the part of his question where he asks if the font is installed on the OS/browser

Answer (score 1):

A web safe font is a font that is considered to be a 'safe bet' to be installed on the vast majority of computers. Every computer that has a browser installed has default fonts built in so that it can display the text on web pages. If it does not have the font specified by the code in the webpage it will use whatever it has been programmed to use.

If the web designer is prudent he or she will set up 'font stacks' that specify 2 or more choices of fonts to pick from so the browser does not have to guess what it should use and can have a couple of choices. Worst case scenario, the browser has to use the standard font it came with such as 'Times New Roman' for the header text and 'Arial' for the body text of the webpages instead of whatever the web designer wanted.

The other choice is for the website to provide the visiting computer with the font by making it available. One of the better ways of doing that is through Google Fonts.

In summary, the computer can only display fonts that either a) it already has installed, or b) fonts that the website makes available from the web.